# Unable to create packages for Windows 10 Store [error APPX1609]

Tags: windows

I'm unable to generate packages for the Windows Store because of this error:

> APPX1609 "The package contains a Debug framework reference 'Name = Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug, MinVersion = 14.0.23019.0, Publisher = 'CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US''. Ensure all framework references in the package are valid frameworks hosted by the Store."

I can't find how to enable the release version of this framework.
I tried to force the value to 'false' in the 'Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets" file, it does not work :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue today. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?